# PHP - script dont GET id value from URL

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm totally stuck with my code.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['kid'];
if (isset($_POST['mainit'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['new_kateg'])){
    $jaunakategorija = $_POST['new_kateg'];
    $kmst = $conn->prepare('UPDATE kategorijas SET kat_vards=:katvards WHERE kat_id=:katid');
    $kmst->bindParam(':katvards', $jaunakategorija);
    $kmst->bindParam(':katid', $id);
    $kmst->execute();

        if($kmst->execute()){
            header('Location: new_kateg.php');
        } else {
            $message = '<p class="red">Kļūda </p>';
        }
    } else {
        $message = '<p class="red">Lauks nedrīkst būt tukšs! </p>';
    }
}
?>


<form action="kateg_edit.php" method="POST">

    <p>Ievadiet jaunās kategorijas nosaukumu</p>
    <?php echo $id; ?>
    <input type="text" name="new_kateg" placeholder="Ievadiet nosaukumu">
    <input type="submit" name="mainit" value="Mainīt!">

</form>
```

This is my code for updating record from database.
My URL is: localhost/....../kateg_edit.php?**kid=2**

when i echo $id it says it's 2. Code do its job but record is not changed.

If i hard code $id ='2';

code works and record that's ID is 2 is changed.

Im stuck why it dont change record when i get the same number from URL!

this is previous page where is button labot(edit)

```
<?php
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM kategorijas");
$query->execute();
$result = $query;

echo 
    "<table class='table-fill'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Kategorijas nosaukums</th>
    <th style='text-align:center;'>Darbība</th>"
    ;

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['kat_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['kat_vards'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td style="text-align:center;"><a href="kateg_edit.php?kid=' . $row['kat_id'] . '">Labot</a>
        <a href="new_kateg.php?deleteid=' . $row['kat_id'] . '">Dzēst</a></td>';
}
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: Wheres the html for you get query which tie the two together?

Comment: Ok so you get the `$_GET['kid']` correct. Is `$_POST['mainit']` and `$_POST['new_kateg']` set && not empty?

Comment: The page to get to the edit page is not relevant, you need to show the code / form where the entry can be edited.

Comment: it's now right under change code

Comment: The main problem is WHY when i set $id='2' record with id 2 is edited from form, but if $id=$_GET['kid']; which i have echo and it says its 2 also why then code works but it dont update the record!! NOT A SINGLE ERROR IS ECHOED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANYWAY THANKS FOR A HELP EVERYONE!

**SOLVED** BY MYSELF!

just inserted one more input field with value from GET and then use in query id which is taken from form.
    ">

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
    $id = $_GET['kid'];
try this
    $id = $_POST['kid'];
instead of 
    method="POST" 
try this
    method="GET"

Comment: why to change? i need to read kid from URL. anyway when i did so error ( Undefined index: kid in kateg_edit.php on line 10)